# Bash script for running postgres docker image failing on linux

Tags: spring, bash, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

The command `which` on line 4 on the script below seems to have an issue, intellij says

> which is non-standard. Use builtin 'command -v' instead

Since `which psql` seems like it is not working it automatically affects line 12 and 13.

While investigating i removed line 4 then the script executed line 6 to 10 which succefully created a docker file(pg-docker) however i also need the `schema.sql` (line 12) and `data.sql` (13) to be executed. Is there an alternative command for `which` command(line 4)

Below is my bash Script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

which psql > /dev/null || (echo "Please ensure that postgres client is in your PATH" && exit 1)

mkdir -p $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres
rm -rf $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres/data

docker run --rm --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=dev -d -p 432:5432 -v $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql postgres
sleep 3
export PGPASSWORD=postgres
psql -U postgres -d dev -h localhost -f schema.sql
psql -U postgres -d dev -h localhost -f data.sql
```

I get the below on the problems on Intellij

[image]

line 4 complains about which command
line 6,7 and 9 complains about $HOME
line 11 complains about PGPASSWORD

Comment: next time you paste a script, please, make sure it's somewhat readable and it doesn't contain unwanted chars such as `12&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` or `<br>` after each line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`which` is used to find and show the full path of a command (in your script it is only used  to make sure the command `psql` is there).
IntelliJ or probably better the defined linter for (bash) scripts suggest not to rely on an separate `which`command but just use the builtin bash-function `command -v` so the line 4 would read

```
command -v psql > /dev/null || (echo "Please ensure that postgres client is in your PATH" && exit 1)
```

That said - it's most likely not your real problem. You need the PostgreSQL Client `psql` installed and in your PATH variable to run the commands in line 12 and 13. Exactly that's what you're checking in line 4 - regardless of using `which` or `command -v`.
How to install the `psql` command depends on your OS.

Comment: thank you i installed postgres and it worked. been sitting with this for sometime now, i will not continue learning ... happy coding